# Force floats to be typeset after their occurrence in the source text?

Tags: floats, positioning

AFAIK a figure or table should always be placed *after* the first reference to it in the text.

So I always place the code for my figures and tables after the paragraph which contains the first reference `\ref` to them.
When I then use the command `\begin{figure}[t]`, it is possible that the figure is placed at the top of the same page where it is referenced, so IMHO that is against the rule mentioned above.

- Is there a way to force `pdflatex` to place the floats after the paragraph which precedes them in the source text?
  (so in my example that would be at the top of the following page or later)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You could try with the `flafter` package:

```
\usepackage{flafter}
```

Comment: +1 I was just going to give the same answer :-) Note that the `flafter` package will make sure that the floats are not placed before their *definition*, e.g. the `figure` or `table` environment, not where it was first `\ref`-erenced. So you need to place this environments close to the first `\ref` to make it work. Also check out the [TeX FAQ](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=floats) for this.

Comment: @Martin Scharrer: Thanks for your comments - mentioning the difference between the definition and the first \ref is an important point (I had already seen that problem and placed the code for the figures accordingly). Thanks again for reminding me of the TeX FAQ which contains useful information.

Comment: Although some years later, thank you very much.

Comment: if you add a suggestion to also try the option `[htp]` then this question can be closed as a dup: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/297564

Answer (score 2):

Or you could replace the `[t]` option with `[b]` so that floats preferentially lie at the page bottom instead of the top if that's suitable to your tastes or needs.