# Forbid LaTeX to place float before mention

Tags: floats, positioning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Force floats to be typeset after their occurrence in the source text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15706/force-floats-to-be-typeset-after-their-occurrence-in-the-source-text)

I've already found houndreds of useful answers. But I can't find anything about this one. Is there an option/workaround to force latex to move a float only backwards, not "front-wards".

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\section*{ONE}

\Blindtext

\textbf{Now I am refering} to a float~\ref{float}. Doesn't matter if it's a table or figure; and then I continue the text.
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{|p{0.8\linewidth}|}
    \hline
    one \\ two \\ three\\ table shouldn't be too small \\ four \\ two \\ eight \\ real eight \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{this is one example}
\label{float}
\end{table} 

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

I know I could use the `b` and `h`-placing options. But when my reference is on the end of a page, it's great that latex puts the float in the top-position of the next page. I actually don't care if it places it `hbt` or `p`. but I don't want it to "appear too early".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `flafter` package. See also https://texfaq.org/FAQ-floats

Answer (score 2):

try `\begin{table}[!htb]`  The `!` allows TeX to ignore float parameters