# Is there a package or a package option for placing figures only after they're referenced?

Tags: floats

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Force floats to be typeset after their occurrence in the source text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15706/force-floats-to-be-typeset-after-their-occurrence-in-the-source-text)

I am currently writing my PhD proposal document. I received a comment from my adviser in his review asking me to place the figures only after they are referenced. I am using the `subfig` package.

In a previous question ([How to use the placement options [t], [h] with figures?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35125/how-to-use-the-placement-options-t-h-with-figures)) I had asked about specific placements of the figures. Here, I am only looking to place it after they referenced.