# Figures after reference in text

Tags: floats, lyx

I'm using LyX and I'd like to ensure that figures do not appear until after they are referenced in the text, ideally at the top of the following page. Is there any way to do this in LyX or LaTeX? I imagine there's some code I can add to the preamble to allow for this, but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: Just load the `flafter` package part of the base latex distribution.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: It's not enough to load the `flafter` package; you need thepackage and make sure that the code for the figure appears close to the first reference.

Comment: Please see the answer and comments to the answer in [`Force floats to be typeset after their occurrence in the source text?`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15706/3954); thic could in fact be a duplicate.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina yes sorry the package forces the figure to appear after the point where figure environment is placed in the source, not explictly after the first reference, although it's usually easy to arrange these are the same. (yes looks like a duplicate)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I did look for information before posting here (I'm a regular on SO and I know the importance of prior research) but I didn't realize that I should search for information on "floats" instead of "figures." This turned out to be more of a meta-question: "How should I refer to figures when I ask the LaTeX community?"